# Multi-class Decision Forest vs Multi-class Decision Jungle

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, multi-class

guys.

I have been learning about machine learning using Azure ML service from Microsoft and my team and I have seen that there are some multi-class decision algorithms, the Forest and Jungle are examples.

We don't know what's the real difference between these ones (we had checked the documentation of them in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/multiclass-decision-forest and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/multiclass-decision-jungle), because they look very similar.

Could you help us with that? What's the difference between these algorithms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided on Decision Jungles states that they split the space by building directed acyclig graphs. Random Forests use trees, which are only a special case of DAGs. It seems like the algorithm is able to fuse nodes, something that isn't happening in constructing a decision tree.

If you follow the link on Decision Jungle's implementation you'll find a [paper that explains the method](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DecisionJunglesNIPS2013.pdf).

From the paper, figure 1:

> Using DAGs instead of trees reduces the number of nodes and can result
>   in better generalization.

For a concrete visualization see page 4 of the [article supplement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DecisionJunglesNIPS2013Supplementary.pdf) - it clearly shows what is built is not a tree, and something more complex.